# how to get first level nodes not inner identical node using xpath

Tags: xpath

I tried below xpath expression but it is not working :

```
//para[not(parent::list-item)]/list
```

the above expression trace inner node too
 I have wrapped the required node with **

```
<book>
  <para>
    **<list>**
      <list-item>
        <para>
          <list>
            <list-item></list-item>
            <list-item></list-item>
            <list-item></list-item>
          </list>
        </para>
      </list-item>
      <list-item></list-item>
    </list>
  </para>
</book>
<para>
  **<list>**
    <list-item>
      <para>
        <list>
          <list-item></list-item>
          <list-item></list-item>
          <list-item></list-item>
        </list>
      </para>
    </list-item>
    <list-item></list-item>
  </list>
</para>
```

Comment: Given that sample XML, can you post elements that you want the XPath to select?

Comment: Thanks for your response,

i want to select only first '<list>' from root node not inner '<list>' (which is the child of list)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how your xpath doesn't do the trick, in the sample you've provided it does select only the top level `list` items.

Nevertheless, here's another approach - select all `list` which are not inside a `list-item` node:

```
//para/list[not(ancestor::list-item)]
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.  It will also work  //para/list[not(self::list)]